# How to concatenate two actions into one (to make it repeatable by '.' and undoable at once)

Tags: vim, undo

Consider a simple example: say, I just typed `foo`, then pressed <kbd>Left</kbd> key, and typed `bar`. Now I have `fobaro`.

When I press <kbd>.</kbd> key, only `bar` part is repeated, and the same is with undo.

So I want the whole `fobaro` to be repeated when I press <kbd>.</kbd>, and to be undid completely at once when I press <kbd>u</kbd>.

I'm just writing plugin ( [auto-pairs-gentle](http://goo.gl/VyOZ0r) ) that does some tricks like that, and I want it not to break undo history.

Comment: This sounds like a job for [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat)!

Comment: No, repeat.vim is useful when I have exact mapping to be repeated. But here (this is plugin "auto-pairs-gentle" by the way) I must repeat all that user typed before plugin "pressed" <Left> key, and after it too, so, I have to remap all the thousand ways of quitting insert mode, and then give to repeat.vim all that user just typed

Comment: If your plugin uses `:` commands, then `:undojoin` may be what you need.

Comment: @benjifisher It can only solve undo problem. `:undojoin` does not alter what will be repeated by dot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't how to relate this to your plugin, but it sounds like you could just record a macro-

```
qq
i
foo<esc><Left>
i
bar<esc>
q
```

then

```
@@
```

To repeat is

Answer (score 0):

When you move the cursor in insert mode, Vim starts a new change; it cannot repeat complex editing sequences, just typed text. Think of complex cursor movements, as those cannot be generally repeated, Vim consistently also doesn't handle something simple (and doable) like `<Left>`.

For your plugin, you can try using lower-level functions like `cursor()` and `setline()` instead. Nonetheless, this is still likely to break repeat of text insertion (at least it will miss any of the low-level modifications). You're reaching the limitations of Vimscript here.

Maybe one of the many existing [auto-close plugins](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters#Plugins) has a clever workaround.